# UglifyJS only compresses my JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea

How to setup UglifyJS in intellij idea to compress and mangle all of my JS files?
Right now I only have compress enabled.

I went over this article: [LINK](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/minifying-javascript.html)

After I setup a file watcher the script seems to work but not in a way that I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the way that you want? It is not clear from the post.

Comment: @suspectus when the script is called from the file watcher I only get a compressed version and I want to use mangler as well.